# chrome.storage.local get returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback, promise

I want to get 2 values from chrome storage via chrome.storage.local.get() but if I try to return the values from the callback function, I get 'undefined'. If I console.log() them, they are actually logged. Why is that? I've read in some other posts, that I need to use a callback - but as far as my basic JS understanding goes, I already return the value from the callback frunction of get().

```
// this should load 2 keys from an object stored in chrome storage
function loadJiraUrlElements(){
    chrome.storage.local.get({companyName: '', jiraBaseUrl: ''}, function(items) {
        return (items.companyName + items.jiraBaseUrl);
     })
}

// I want to use this function to call the return value and populate a DOM element
function populateUrlFieldsWithUrlElements(){
    companyInput.value = loadJiraUrlElements()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an `async` function, you can either wrap it under a Promise object or continue using the callback mechanism.

1.) Promise:

```
function loadJiraUrlElements() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        chrome.storage.local.get({companyName: '', jiraBaseUrl: ''}, function(items) {
            resolve(items.companyName + items.jiraBaseUrl);
         })
    });
}

// And caller function changes to 
function populateUrlFieldsWithUrlElements(){
    loadJiraUrlElements().then(function(value) {
        companyInput.value = value;
    })
}
```

2.) Callback:

```
function loadJiraUrlElements(cb){
    chrome.storage.local.get({companyName: '', jiraBaseUrl: ''}, function(items) {
        cb && cb(items.companyName + items.jiraBaseUrl);
     })
}

function populateUrlFieldsWithUrlElements(){
    loadJiraUrlElements(function(value) {
        companyInput.value = value;
    })

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're getting `undefined` because you're returning to the callback function (ie the inner function), not the outer function, which you are trying to get the return value from.

You can use a promise with `resolve` so you can use a `.then` callback in your `populateUrlFieldsWithUrlElements` function to get the value you want:

```
function loadJiraUrlElements() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.storage.local.get({companyName: '', jiraBaseUrl: ''}, function(items) {
      resolve(items.companyName + items.jiraBaseUrl);
    })
  })
}

// I want to use this function to call the return value and populate a DOM element
function populateUrlFieldsWithUrlElements() {
  loadJiraUrlElements().then(result => {
    companyInput.value = result;
  })
}
```

Or you can use `async`/`await` in your second function if you don't wish to use the `.then` callback:

```
// I want to use this function to call the return value and populate a DOM element
async function populateUrlFieldsWithUrlElements() {
  companyInput.value = await loadJiraUrlElements();
}
```